# Javascript: Do a function before entering text in an 'input' tag

Tags: javascript

I've a text input with an 'onkeypress' event that activates a function. The function checks if the value of that input is empty, in case it's empty, an alert activates.

The problem is that first enters the character THEN performs the onkeypress event acts. What I want to do is that Javascript performs first the function THEN the key is entered.

I don't know how to do it with only Javascript (so I can't use jQuery)

Comment: do you wanna run this function when page loads?

Comment: Why not call function on blur and focus? You can always save previous value and on failure reset to it

Comment: attach all function to input box i.e onkeydown,onkeypress,onkeyup,onchange it will give proper results

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qs2sothz/ — I can't reproduce the problem. The alert fires showing that the value is blank.

Comment: Yep, as Akshay padwal said, calling the function at the input box (instead of using an Event Listener) worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

The `keypress` is actually the combination of `keydown` and then `keyup` (of the same key!). If you want to catch the key before the user leaves the keyboard you should use the `keydown` instead of `keypress`:

```js
document.getElementById('a1').onkeydown = function() {
  alert(this.value);
}
```

```html
<input id="a1" />
```